# Basic Time-Series Histogram with R

Tags: r, time-series, histogram

I have a dataframe that looks like so:

```
> x
                Timestamp Calls
1   [2014-11-13 20:40:02]    18
2   [2014-11-13 20:40:05]    16
3   [2014-11-13 20:40:11]    15
```

and so on.

I would like to plot a histogram with 'Timestamp' values as the range and 'Calls' as the domain. What is the most straightforward way to do so?

Keep in mind, I have very little experience with R, so this is very much an R 101 question. Thanks!

Comment: I should also probably scrub the brackets "[" "]" from the data in the source csv file, too

Comment: I don't think you mean a histogram - you want to plot the values in `Calls` vs the values in `Timestamp`?

Comment: @keegan that might be what I *actually* want...

Comment: @keegan yes, that is most certainly what I want `plot(x$Timestamp, x$Calls`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a slightly better approach that suited my needs in this particular case.

First, convert the timestamp to a plain integer to place on the x-axis:

```
Timeframe=as.numeric(strptime(Timeframe, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
```

Now, for the visualization I'm looking for, I can use `ggplot`:

```
raw_data <-read.csv("serverName.data.20150116.csv")
data <- transform(raw_data, Seconds=as.numeric(strptime(Timeframe, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")))

p<-ggplot(count_data, aes(Seconds, Calls))+geom_point(color="blue")
p
```

And then I get a decent visualization of the data:
[image]
Playing with the graphical options in `ggplot` could give me more informative visualization, but as far as a straightforward plot to aid diagnostics, this will do.

Answer (score 0):

```
df<-data.frame(time=c(1,2,3),Calls=c(18,16,15))
plot(df$time,df$Calls,type='l')
```

Take a look at `?plot` for more details about `R`'s basic plotting methods.